# how many time heightForRowAtIndexPath being called before view Presentation? Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I'm developing an `iPad` app, and I have found this problem, why when I present `tableView` , the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` it's called more than one time for each row?

For Example if I have ten row, the method will be calls 30 times.

Comment: this method call of scroll view scrolling that this method call means you are display total row time call after you are scroll that this method call.

Comment: Why is this a problem?  Delegate methods are called as often as the delegate user (table view) finds necessary.

Comment: Because if I have 3 line no prob, but if I have 10000 line?

Comment: in short you get about as many that makes "one screen worth" of cells.

Comment: The number of calls necessary takes into account the scroll position (contentOffset) too.  Otherwise, it doesn't know which cell should be at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `numberOfSectionsInTableView` which is called once, and `numberOfRowsInSection`, which is called once per section, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for each row. Generally, the component needs to find out how many rows it needs to create (which translates to how many row cells it needs to allocate) so it keeps calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` until the total height is sufficient to cover the area of the screen, plus a few more rows for the scroll.

In your situation it looks like the screen is high enough to fit some 30 rows of your table; hence, you get thirty calls to `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. These calls will be followed by roughly as many calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a table view is displayed, it calls `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on the delegate for each of its rows. so if you scroll your tableview then this method get called, when system layouting your cell then also this method get called.

[Refer apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc),

> The method allows the delegate to specify rows with varying heights. If this method is implemented, the value it returns overrides the value specified for the rowHeight property of UITableView for the given row.
>
> There are performance implications to using
>   tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of the rowHeight property.
>   Every time a table view is displayed, it calls
>   tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its
>   rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table
>   views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

So, it's better to not implement this method when there are too much rows!